# ValueError: too many values to unpack (NLTK classifier)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, naivebayes

I'm doing classification analysis using NLTK's Naive Bayes classifier. I insert a tsv file containing records and labels.

But the file doesn't get trained due to an error. Here's my python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('tweets.txt', delimiter ='\t', quoting = 3)

dataset.isnull().any()

dataset = dataset.fillna(method='ffill')

import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
corpus = []
for i in range(0,16004):
    tweet = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['tweet'][i])
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    tweet = [ps.stem(word) for word in tweet if not word in 
    set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet)
    corpus.append(tweet)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 10000)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values




from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, 
random_state = 0)
train_set, test_set = X_train[500:], y_train[:500]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

The error is:

```
File "C:\Users\HSR\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py", line 194, in train
for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Where did labeled_featuresets come from?

Comment: It's a variable of the function NaiveBayesClassifier.train()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLTKClassifier doesn't work like scikit estimators. It requires the `X` and `y` both in a single array which is then passed to `train()`.

But in your code, you are only supplying it the X_train and it tries to unpack `y` from that and hence the error.

The NaiveBayesClassifier requires the input to be a list of tuples where list denotes the training samples and the tuple has the feature dictionary and label inside. Something like:

```
X = [({feature1:'val11', feature2:'val12' .... }, class1),
     ({feature1:'val21', feature2:'val22' .... }, class2), 
     ...
     ...                                                  ]
```

You need to change your input to this format.

```
feature_names = cv.get_feature_names()
train_set = []
for i, single_sample in enumerate(X):
    single_feature_dict = {}
    for j, single_feature in enumerate(single_sample):
        single_feature_dict[feature_names[j]]=single_feature
    train_set.append((single_feature_dict, y[i]))
```

**Note**: The above for loop can be shortened by using dict comprehension but I'm not that fluent there.

Then you can do this:

```
nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do it, but I get a Memory error. My dataset is too large. Any way to apply the loop in small increments instead of applying y[i] to the whole dataset at one go??

Comment: @SriReka y[i] should be a single value, the class label of that individual sample. So my code is doing it incrementally only one at a time. Your system is holding X and y in the memory so the only wat memoryError occurs here is when the data is duplicated from X to the train_set tuples. This can be avoided by first writing the tuple format to a file and then in a new program reading it again. This way at a single time X and train_set will not be present.

Comment: Thank you so much!!. I have successfully trained the classifier without any memory errors. But I have a doubt. In your code, in the last line, train_set.append((single_dict, y[i])) , single_dict is undefined. I tried it with single_feature_dict. Is it right??

Comment: @SriReka Yes, that was a typo. Fixed now. Thanks.